# How to make a Carousel out of Go/Hugo Iteration Markup

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-4, hugo

I'm creating a Go/Hugo Theme with Bootstrap 4 and in my `index.html` template file I have the code below to iterate through the articles posted:

```html
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12" id="main">
    
      <div class="row">
    
        {{- range .Paginator.Pages -}}
          {{- if eq .Type "posts"}}
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          <figure><a href="{{ .Permalink }}"><img src="{{ .Params.banner }}" /></a></figure>
          <p>{{ .Summary }}</p>
        </div>
          {{- end -}}
        {{- end }}
    
      </div>

    </div>
```

It's not quite ready yet but it already allows me to use a cover image, defined as a FrontMatter parameter, for something more creative than a blog-like style. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx8oK.png), a sneak-peak.

As you can see there as Pagination implemented as well so I can see whatever is older the the last entries (defined in `config.toml` and accessed through `.Paginator.Pages`).

But I was thinking on get rid of this Pagination and transform this listing in a Carousel, but I don't if I would be able to do so with Hugo nor if it's possible to "plug n' play" a Carousel that would working with Bootstrap's existing markup.

How could I accomplish that?

Comment: I created my own ready-to-use lightweight carousel for Hugo. You can find it here: https://hugocodex.org/add-ons/slider-carousel/. If you have any questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do it in HTML then you can do it with Hugo, so the answer is yes, it's possible. From a brief search on the net there seem to be dozens of carousel implementations for Bootstrap, so just choose one of those.

For example, with the [carousel for Bootstrap v4 alpha](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#example) on the Bootstrap site, you can make a carousel with this code:

```html
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Assuming that you have defined the parameters `carouselimage` and `carouselimagealt` in the front matter of all your articles, you could generate this HTML with Hugo by doing this:

```html
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    {{ $paginator := .Paginate (where .Data.Pages "Type" "posts") }}
    {{ range $paginator.Pages }}
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{{ .Data.carouselimage }}" alt="{{ .Data.carouselimagealt }}">
      </div>
    {{ end }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, I've made your page type here "posts" as you did in your question, but usually in Hugo it is "post", so you might want to check which one you need.

Comment: Thank you for your time. After posting the question I realized that in the end it's just HTML. Go/Hugo shouldn't interfere in anything. However I ended up using bxSlider instead of Bootstrap. It has more options. And regarding the `Type`, at least while I study Hugo's permalinks better, for now I changed it on purpose